# Laptop heatsink temperature

Tags: laptop, cooling, heatsink

Which software can be used to measure the laptop heatsink (not cpu) temperature near the fan? Are there any alternate methods to measure the heat sink temperature (experimental or software based or by calculation)? 
Any website which might provide me charts/graphs/relations between cpu temperature or fan speed and heat sink temperature?
Just to estimate, what is the general heatsink temperature? In my case, the cooling fan starts running when cpu reaches 66.8 degree C, so what can the heat sink temperature be after the fan has been running for say half an hour?

Comment: this completely depends on the ambient tempurature, your CPU type, and weather it's busy doing a lot

Comment: Can I get the pertinent relations anywhere on the web? I know the ambient and cpu temperatures.. how do I obtain the heatsink temperature from it?

Comment: Get you an infrared heat sensor gun

Comment: if you're talking specifically about the heatsink temp, you're probably out of luck. If your CPU is making proper contact, then it should be around the same temp, save for the fins which should be cooler due to the fan blowing on them. Maybe a better question is why it matters to know your heatsink temp?

Comment: My college does have an infrared temperature sensor gun, so we'll try using that..

Comment: I'm working on a project in which we are planning to supply air at below ambient temperatures to the fan inlet so it can better cool the heat sink.. So for determining the amount of cooling required for the air, we need to know the heatsink temperature..

Answer (score 0):

First you'd need a heat sink with a sensor. Then the software would need to be something designed to work with that sensor and a device that sensor connects to possibly. They do make wireless heat sensors you could check out. I goggled it but making direct recommendations isn't allowed in these forums.

Being it is a heat disapation device though the temperature from the part touching the cpu to the part furthest away would be drastically diffrent because it's designed to disapate the heat.